# Spark UI storage tab shows more RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

I am running a spark streaming application. The app uses MapWithStateRDD to manage state across batches. App and setup details:

- Nodes: 2
- Memory per executor: 3 GB
- Num of partitions for MapWithStateRDD: 200
- Standalone mode
- Batch size: 20 sec
- Timeout duration: 1 minute
- Checkpointing enabled
- Checkpoint duration: 1 minute
- Spark version: 2.2

I am not caching or checkpointing any RDD except MapWithStateRDD which Spark automatically checkpoints. What I have noticed is that the storage tab shows not just 3 (i.e. 60/20) MapWithStateRDDs but more (check attached picture). The list keeps on becoming longer as more batches are processed. How to understand this?[image: Spark Storage Tab Content]

Code snippet showing read from kafka and using mapwithState:

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, MyClass>> records = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                    jssc,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, MyClass>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));

JavaPairDStream<String, MyClass> converted = records.mapToPair(consRecord -> {
    return new Tuple2<String, MyClass>(consRecord.key(), consRecord.value());
});

JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, MyClass, Session, Session> stateDstream = converted.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc).timeout(Durations.minutes(Long.parseLong(conf.get("spark.state.timeout.interval")))).numPartitions(200));
```

Comment: someone got a clue?

Comment: can you please post code?

Comment: @zhuang: added the relevant code snippet. Storage tab shows multiple MapWithStateRDDs. I am not caching or checkpointing any RDD as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: I guess one way to debug first is to set `timeout` to seconds and observe if any cached rdds are being removed or they just keep piling up. Another idea, if you haven't tested already, is to just do a `state.remove()` in your `mappingFunc`.

Comment: i am already using state.remove() based on my state machine. I can see that RDDs disappear and appear as and when new batches are processed. The only problem I see is that a RDD is retained far longer than it should be.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solution? I am facing the same problem

Comment: @amanpreet: I had to explicitly checkpoint MapWithStateRDD. Merely setting the checkpoint duration in spark context was not enough.

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate a bit more please? 
So far what i understand is that,  mapWIthState checkpoints after 
every 10 * batchInterval time. So , if you have batch interval of 10 seconds, it will checkpoint data after 100 seconds. So it will keep those 10 RDDs in memory until it checkpoints.

Bu this becomes a problem if your state is too large. So if you have found a solution, can you elaborate?